# Is a BatchRequest restricted to one calendar?

Tags: c#, google-api, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm having trouble with the BatchRequest and working with the Google Calendar Api V3 in C# .NET (MVC 5).

The following code is working but not something I want.

```
ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext ();

foreach (Calendar calendar in db.Calendars.ToList())
{
    BatchRequest br = new BatchRequest(service);

    // This returns events within a specified date range
    List<Event> evts =
        GoogleServiceSingleton.Instance.GetAllEventsWithinTimeSpan(calendar.GoogleID, DateTime.Parse("23-12-2015"), DateTime.Parse("24-12-2015")).ToList();

    foreach (Event e in evts)
    {
        br.Queue<Event>(
                service.Events.Delete(calendar.GoogleID, e.Id),
                (content, error, i, message) =>
                {
                    // Put your callback code here.
                });
    }

    if (!Settings.debug)
    {
        br.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

What I want is to create a BatchRequest for all calendars. In that case my BatchRequest object is created outside the foreach loop and queued inside. After the foreach has finished, ExecuteAsync is called.

The BatchRequest is filled with the right events, but after ExecuteAsync had been called, no events are deleted. Can someone tell me why?

```
ProjectContext db = new ProjectContext ();

BatchRequest br = new BatchRequest(service);

foreach (Calendar calendar in db.Calendars.ToList())
{
    List<Event> evts =
        GoogleServiceSingleton.Instance.GetAllEventsWithinTimeSpan(calendar.GoogleID, DateTime.Parse("23-12-2015"), DateTime.Parse("24-12-2015")).ToList();

    foreach (Event e in evts)
    {
        br.Queue<Event>(
                service.Events.Delete(calendar.GoogleID, e.Id),
                (content, error, i, message) =>
                {
                    // Put your callback code here.
                });
    }   
}

if (!Settings.debug)
{
    br.ExecuteAsync();
}
```

Comment: do you think `but that is not working`  explain your problem?

Comment: Thnx for your comment @Eser, i have updated my post